# IO.pipe(Encoding::BINARY, Encoding::BINARY) failing with UndefinedConversionError, but only under Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, io

I have some code for converting from [http.rb](https://github.com/httprb/http)'s chunk-based response body streaming to an ordinary `IO`.

```rb
def stream_response_body(body)
  IO.pipe(Encoding::BINARY, Encoding::BINARY) do |rd, wr|
    t = copying_thread(body, wr)
    yield rd
  ensure
    t.join if t
  end
end

def copying_thread(body, dst)
  Thread.new do
    body.each { |chunk| dst.write(chunk) }
  rescue StandardError => e
    UCBLIT::TIND.logger.error(e)
  ensure
    dst.close
    Thread.exit
  end
end
```

This works fine when I call it from a command-line script, but when I call it from a Rails controller,  `dst.write(chunk)` blows up with:

```
  Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xE5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
    /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bundler/gems/ucblit-tind-de599ab253cc/lib/ucblit/tind/api/api.rb:106:in `write'
    /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bundler/gems/ucblit-tind-de599ab253cc/lib/ucblit/tind/api/api.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in copying_thread'
```

(Script and Rails app are both running under Ruby 2.7.2 on macOS Catalina.)

I've stripped the reading code down to reading byte-by-byte just to make sure the issue wasn't being caused by some downstream library:

```rb
response = HTTP.get(url, encoding: Encoding::BINARY)
status = response.status
raise(HTTP::ResponseError, status.to_s) unless status.success?

xml_str_io = StringIO.new
xml_str_io.set_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)

stream_response_body(response.body) do |body|
  while (b = body.read(1))
    xml_str_io.putc(b)
  end
end
```

Why (and where!) is the `ASCII-8BIT` to `UTF-8` conversion happening at all? And why only when called from Rails?

---

**Update:**

I tried the following modifications, neither of which worked:

1. packed byte array instead of raw string

   ```rb
   body.each do |chunk|
     byteStr = chunk.bytes.pack('C*')
     dst.write(byteStr)
   end
   ```
2. use `putc` instead of `write`

   ```rb
      body.each do |chunk|
        chunk.bytes.each do |b|
          dst.putc(b)
        end
      end
   ```

Interestingly, in the second case, I still see `write` in the backtrace:

```
  Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xE5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
    /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bundler/gems/ucblit-tind-de599ab253cc/lib/ucblit/tind/api/api.rb:108:in `write'
    /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bundler/gems/ucblit-tind-de599ab253cc/lib/ucblit/tind/api/api.rb:108:in `putc'
    /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bundler/gems/ucblit-tind-de599ab253cc/lib/ucblit/tind/api/api.rb:108:in `block (3 levels) in copying_thread'
```

I assume this failing `write` (and probably the others) is in `IO`'s C code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Rails sets the default encoding to UTF8

```rb
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/291a3d2ef29a3842d1156ada7526f4ee60dd2b59/railties/lib/rails.rb#L22-L23

I believe you need to set the encoding on your writer pipe otherwise it will use the default encoding.

```rb
read_io, write_io = IO.pipe(Encoding::BINARY, Encoding::BINARY, binmode: true)
write_io.set_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)

write_io.write([serialized_object].pack('NA*'), encoding: 'BINARY')
```